# .NET verifying POST request result

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping

I need my application to log in on site with user defined login and password. Although sending POST data is very simple I can't manage how to check if returned page shows "logged in" or "wrong password" statement.

Searching .html string for specified statement is too slow and comparing pre-seted error page is not working because page is dynamic loaded (with same url).

Is there any lib for managing .html content? I could use java or python as well as c# if i had to

Comment: What about interrogating with fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some research and found that regular expression perfectly fits my problem as they are **easy to implement**, and **really fast in that case**.

If anyone would also have a problem like that:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// .html document returned by page
string webRequestResponse = getResponse();
// site error string
const string REGEX = "Password is not correct.";
// check if page contain that error
bool wrongPassword = Regex.IsMatch(webRequestResponse, REGEX);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Eat Your Cookies

The majority of websites will use cookies to track the current user's session across multiple requests. You'll have to attach a cookie storage to your WebRequest when sending the POST request, and inspect the storage for the login response.

Each website will implement their session tracking differently. So there is no one solution fits all, but for most cases all you'll have to do is verify that a cookie exists under a given name. What the cookie contains doesn't matter, but when that cookie exists you know login was successful.

That cookie storage will have to be used for additional requests from the server for that user session. So you'll likely need to track cookies anyway.

Websites can use other methods to track user sessions, including a session ID in GET parameters or use the web servers persistent connection.

I don't know to many websites that log user's in that don't use cookies to track user sessions. I'd look there first.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with logging in via a script, web-sites return `200 OK` response on both of login outcomes: logged in or not logged in. So you'll have to parse the incoming html for the required string to verify successful credential check. There is no other way for that, unless the site provides some API.

The best way to parse resulting HTML is using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). I've used it in the past and it was a blast to get the required strings out of the pages.